# SharePoint 2010 Quick Launch is missing

Tags: quick-launch

Recently our client complained `Quick Launch` is missing. The `Quick Launch` menu in sites is temperamental.

Sometimes it appears and works fine, other times it completely disappears.

I checked the site settings, master page, Timer jobs everything is working fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you just provide more screen shots to support your question?

Comment: Are you changing the SharePoint look by different theme?

Comment: There is no change in themes, A custom master page is used, but it works fine on UAT.

Comment: Please check if  **Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl** applied on Quick Launch inside your custom master page.

Comment: But this appears sometimes, there is nothing to do with SPSecurityTrimmedControl

Answer (score 1):

try going to `/_layouts/quiklnch.aspx`

This should have Quick Launch settings, or go to `Site Settings > Navigation`, and check out the Global and Current Navigation Links. I believe Current Navigation applies to the Quick Launch

Comment: All settings in navigation are in default mode ie show the contents inside the site. Even settings not changed even after quick launch disappeared. It becomes invisible sometime around 10 am and visible at end of business hours.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if what you are talking about is the same issue I had, but it sounds similar.

I created several quick launch links in a few different groups. If I navigated to a different page using the promoted web links, the quick launch was properly populated. If I used any of the links I set up, then the quick launch would not display properly. Instead I would get a single group of links. No headers were displayed and no links from other groups were displayed. This even occurred if I navigated back to the home page from one of the quick launch links.

What solved my issue was adding a slash "/" (without quotes) to the end of the urls for the links.

**site/SharedDocuments** did not work (links disappeared)

**site/SharedDocuments/** did work (all links displayed on the page)